# Where is Undo/Redo located on the Ribbon Tab in Microsoft Office 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

Undo/Redo action is located on the [quick access toolbar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA012341051033.aspx) in Microsoft Office 2007, but can we find it on the Ribbon Tab? If yes, at where?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default they're not in the Ribbon Tab but in the Quick Access Toolbar, Top Left, next to the Save button. Note that the Redo button is only activated after an Undo.

[image]

If what you're trying to do is customize the Ribbon, [Microsoft's answer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA102277541033.aspx) is:

> The Ribbon, which is part of the
>   Microsoft Office Fluent user
>   interface, is designed to help you
>   quickly find the commands that you
>   need to complete a task. Commands are
>   organized in logical groups that are
>   collected together under tabs. Because
>   each tab relates to a type of
>   activity, such as writing or laying
>   out a page, it is not possible to
>   customize the Ribbon without using XML
>   and programming code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [official Microsoft page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP012163941033.aspx) showing you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add it to my quick access bar because it couldn't be found otherwise.  CTRL-z is my favorite in anycase.

Comment: and Ctrl+Y for redo!